# OTA_HotelResRQ direct sell fails with FORMAT ERROR ON OPTIONAL FIELD

Tags: sabre

I'm making the following sequence of calls to reserve a hotel room using the direct sell request:

1. HotelPropertyDescriptionRQ
2. PassengerDetailsRQ
3. OTA_HotelResRQ

The final response errors with:

```
FORMAT ERROR ON OPTIONAL FIELD
```

I'm unable to work out what is causing this error - is it perhaps the RPH of the room is not being correctly added to the PassengerDetailsRQ?

The OTA_HotelResRQ is:

```
<OTA_HotelResRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ReturnHostCommand="true" TimeStamp="2017-02-13T12:45:24" Version="2.2.0">
<Hotel>
  <BasicPropertyInfo RPH="001">
    <ConfirmationNumber>PWBA-POW-131c-02</ConfirmationNumber>
  </BasicPropertyInfo>
  <Guarantee Type="G">
    <CC_Info>
      <PaymentCard Code="VI" ExpireDate="2018-10" Number="4111111111111111"/>
      <PersonName>
        <Surname>TEST</Surname>
      </PersonName>
    </CC_Info>
  </Guarantee>
  <RoomType NumberOfUnits="1"/>
</Hotel>
```

The HotelPropertyDescriptionRQ:

```
<HotelPropertyDescriptionRQ Version="2.3.0" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10">
  <AvailRequestSegment>
<GuestCounts Count="1" />
<HotelSearchCriteria>
  <Criterion>
    <HotelRef HotelCode="0007855" />
  </Criterion>
</HotelSearchCriteria>
<TimeSpan End="2016-12-17" Start="2016-12-10"/>     
  </AvailRequestSegment>
</HotelPropertyDescriptionRQ>
```

The PassengerDetailsRQ:

```
<PassengerDetailsRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_3" version="3.3.0" IgnoreOnError="false" HaltOnError="true">
  <PostProcessing IgnoreAfter="false" RedisplayReservation="true" UnmaskCreditCard="true">
<EndTransactionRQ>
  <EndTransaction Ind="true"></EndTransaction>
  <Source ReceivedFrom="PW TESTING"/>
</EndTransactionRQ>

  </PostProcessing>
  <PreProcessing IgnoreBefore="false">
<UniqueID ID=""/>
  </PreProcessing>
  <SpecialReqDetails>
<AddRemarkRQ>
  <RemarkInfo>
    <FOP_Remark>
      <CC_Info Suppress="true">
    <PaymentCard Code="VI" ExpireDate="2017-12" Number="4444333322221111" SuppressApprovalCode="true"/>
      </CC_Info>
    </FOP_Remark>
  </RemarkInfo>
</AddRemarkRQ>
  </SpecialReqDetails>
  <TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
    <AgencyInfo>
  <Address>
        <AddressLine>XXXXXXXXXXX Ltd</AddressLine>
        <CityName>London</CityName>
        <CountryCode>GB</CountryCode>
        <PostalCode>XXXX XXX</PostalCode>
        <StateCountyProv StateCode="LN" />
        <StreetNmbr>2 Some Rome</StreetNmbr>
  </Address>
    </AgencyInfo>
    <CustomerInfo>
  <ContactNumbers>
    <ContactNumber NameNumber="1.1" Phone="817-555-1212" PhoneUseType="H" />
  </ContactNumbers>
  <PersonName Infant="false" NameNumber="1.1">
    <GivenName>Iain</GivenName>
    <Surname>TESTING</Surname>
  </PersonName>
    </CustomerInfo>
  </TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
</PassengerDetailsRQ>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is because you are adding a confirmation number to the sell request, which is an optional field when selling passive segments, but it should not be expected when actually requesting the room to the hotel.

```
<ConfirmationNumber>PWBA-POW-131c-02</ConfirmationNumber>
```

I would try removing that.

Answer (score 0):

To reserve a hotel room using the direct sell request from sabre used OTA_HotelResRQ request.

Here is one example for request (i already used this request and get response from sabre)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<OTA_HotelResRQ Version="2.2.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    -<Hotel xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10">
    <BasicPropertyInfo RPH="001"/>
    <Customer NameNumber="01.01"/>
    -<Guarantee Type="G">
        -<CC_Info>
            <PaymentCard Number="3782 8224 6310 005" ExpireDate="2021-09" Code="AX"/>
            -<PersonName>
            <Surname>tailor</Surname>
            </PersonName>
        </CC_Info>
    </Guarantee>
    <RoomType NumberOfUnits="1"/>
    </Hotel>
</OTA_HotelResRQ>
```